# What is the Laurent series representation of $f(z)=\frac{1}{z(1-z)(4-z)}$?

Tags: complex-analysis, taylor-expansion, laurent-series

What is the Laurent series representation of $f(z)=\frac{1}{z(1-z)(4-z)}$?

My solution: Using partial fractions, $f(z)=\frac{1}{4z} + \frac{1}{3(1-z)} - \frac{1}{12(4-z)}$

Hence, $$f(z)=\frac{1}{4} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n (z-1)^n + \frac{1}{3} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} z^n - \frac{1}{48} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{z^n}{4^n}$$

Is this correct? And how can I put every term under just one summation?

Comment: $\frac{1}{4z}$ is already in a Laurent series representation, the other two sums you can just put them together

Comment: You should also note that this is just one possible Laurent series: the one valid in the annulus $0<|z|<1$.  Other annuli, such as $1<|z|<4$ or $0<|z-1|<1$ will lead to different Laurent series.  This is the right form to compute the residue at 0.